# OSX Native API Video Decoding C++

Tags: c++, macos, avfoundation, core-video

Recently, I completed an audio decoding task using Apple Core Audio C++ API.

Now I am interested in decoding and getting raw uncompressed data of frames of a video file again with native OSX API with C++ (the analog of DirectShow or Media Foundation on Windows OS).

I have looked at available APIs (AVFoundation, Core Video, etc.) but couldn't find the framework which will do the job and is accessible through C++.

So my question which is the most suitable framework to pick up for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read raw video data from a file using `AVFoundation`'s `AVAssetReader`.

You create an `AVAssetReader`, add a `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` with `nil` output settings then call `copyNextSampleBuffer()` until finished.

However, unless you've got very specific needs, you're unlikely to find the raw codec video data very useful. Are you trying to display the video? In that case `AVPlayerLayer` / `AVPlayer` (`AVFoundation` once again) are probably what you're looking for. If you want something lower level, `CoreMedia`/`VideoToolbox` may be for you. `AVFoundation` is an objective c framework so you'll be using objective-c++, while `CoreMedia` and `VideoToolbox` are C frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to put this project aside for a while and now I'm restarting my work on this. I just need to get the raw uncompressed rgb values of pixels frame by frame. I want to perform custom filter on the video (something I have implemented on my own), so the raw pixel data is exactly what I need to get from the input file. I will give your suggestion a try and let you know about the results. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, for frame data you need to pass non nil options, specifying rgba (probably). I can update my answer.

Comment: That would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Someone closed this question

Comment: Ooooh, I see, this is bad. Maybe I will take a time to investigate it by myself (I think I might be able to handle it). Just another quick question: AVFoundation vs VideoToolbox: which one to pick up (in terms of better functional and more audio format/codec support)?

Comment: You want AVFoundation’s AVAssetReader. Searching for kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA should help, e.g. this question with answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051630/22147